# SignalR : Not invoking method in hub to return JSON in real-time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am on the verge of returning JSON in real-time while a performance monitoring process is running using SignalR (although it not working). Currently I can get the full JSON to return once the process is completed, but I want to implement it such that it returns JSON every second when the app gets the value from the program counter. The problem is, my Invoke call is simply not doing anything at all, even though I explicitly return data to be sent to the browser during each value retrieved from performance monitoring.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API to develop an API, and am calling the API via URL in the browser and it is returning JSON. I am attempting to use SignalR to have the app send JSON to the browser, but it is not doing anything at all. Rather, the application simply returns the completed JSON from the controller action with all of the performance data values once the process has completed. In other words, SignalR is not working.

So, I need some help figuring out why SignalR isn't sending any data to the browser so I can get a live feed and wrap up this project.

DO NOTE: Since I'm sending JSON directly to the browser, the call to do so is done in a model class rather than a view, simply because you can't work with a view when you're returning JSON via a URL call to a Web API. Keep in mind I am not working with a view, but just with the browser and a URL call to the API.

Any help pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, and thank you. I apologize if I'm asking a stupid question, but I've been laboring over this and simply cannot find the solution.

Here is my hub class. It is located in ~/signalr and is in a file called LiveHub.cs. The method Send is what I am trying to invoke in the method seen in the next code block.

```
namespace PerfMon2.signalr
{
    public class LiveHub : Hub
    {

        public List<DataValueInfo> Send(List<DataValueInfo> data)
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method from LogDBRepository.cs that includes the SignalR calls.

```
public List<LogInfo> LogTimedPerfData(string macName, string categoryName, string counterName,
                                          string instanceName, string logName, string live, long? seconds)
    {
        iModsDBRepository modsDB = new iModsDBRepository();
        List<MachineInfo> theMac = modsDB.GetMachineByName(macName);

        if (theMac.Count == 0)
            return new List<LogInfo>();

        else if (instanceName == null)
        {
            if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counterName, categoryName, macName) )
            {
                return new List<LogInfo>();
            }
        }
        else if (instanceName != null)
        {
            if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counterName, categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instanceName, categoryName, macName))
            {
                return new List<LogInfo>();
            }
        }
        else if (logName == null)
        {
            return new List<LogInfo>();
        }

        // Check if entered log name is a duplicate for the authenticated user
        List<LogInfo> checkDuplicateLog = this.GetSingleLog(logName);
        if (checkDuplicateLog.Count > 0)
        {
            return new List<LogInfo>();
        }

        PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(categoryName, theMac[0].MachineName);
        if (category.CategoryName == null || category.MachineName == null)
        {
            return new List<LogInfo>();
        }

        List<LogInfo> logIt = new List<LogInfo>();
        if (category.CategoryType != PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance)
        {
            List<InstanceInfo> instances = modsDB.GetInstancesFromCatMacName(theMac[0].MachineName, category.CategoryName);

            foreach (InstanceInfo inst in instances)
            {
                if (!category.InstanceExists(inst.InstanceName))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (inst.InstanceName.Equals(instanceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName,
                                                                        inst.InstanceName, theMac[0].MachineName);

                    //CounterSample data = perfCounter.NextSample();
                    //double value = CounterSample.Calculate(data, perfCounter.NextSample());
                    string data = "";
                    List<UserInfo> currUser = this.GetUserByName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                    string timeStarted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

                    List<string> dataValues = new List<string>();

                    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/PerfMon2");
                    hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    var perfMon = hubConnection.CreateProxy("LiveHub");
                    // perfMon.On("sendValue", message => Console.WriteLine(message));
                    hubConnection.Start().Wait();

                    List<DataValueInfo> lol = new List<DataValueInfo>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
                    {
                        data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
                        //dataValues[i] = data;
                        dataValues.Add(data);
                        lol.Add(new DataValueInfo
                        {
                            Value = perfCounter.NextValue().ToString()
                        });
                        perfMon.Invoke<List<DataValueInfo>>("Send", lol);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    string timeFinished = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

                    Log log = new Log
                    {
                        LogName = logName,
                        CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                        InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                        CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                        MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                        TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                        TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                        PerformanceData = string.Join(",", dataValues),
                        UserID = currUser[0].UserID
                    };
                    this.CreateLog(log);
                    logIt.Add(new LogInfo
                    {
                        LogName = logName,
                        CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                        InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                        CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                        MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                        TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                        TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                        PerformanceData = dataValues.ToList<string>()
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName,
                                                                        "", theMac[0].MachineName);


            string data = "";
            List<UserInfo> currUser = this.GetUserByName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            string timeStarted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

            //string[] dataValues = new string[(int)seconds];
            List<string> dataValues = new List<string>();

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/PerfMon2");
            hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            var perfMon = hubConnection.CreateProxy("LiveHub");
            // perfMon.On("sendValue", message => Console.WriteLine(message));
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();

            List<DataValueInfo> lol = new List<DataValueInfo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
            {
                data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
                //dataValues[i] = data;
                dataValues.Add(data);
                lol.Add(new DataValueInfo
                {
                    Value = perfCounter.NextValue().ToString()
                });
                perfMon.Invoke<List<DataValueInfo>>("Send", lol);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            string timeFinished = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

            Log log = new Log
            {
                LogName = logName,
                CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                PerformanceData = string.Join(",", dataValues),
                UserID = currUser[0].UserID
            };              
            this.CreateLog(log);
            logIt.Add(new LogInfo
            {
                LogName = logName,
                CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                PerformanceData = dataValues.ToList<string>()
            });
        }
        return logIt;
    }
```

Here is the controller for the method in LogController.cs :

```
  [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public List<LogInfo> Log_Perf_Data(string machine_name, string category_name, string counter_name, string instance_name,
                                   string log_name, long? seconds, string live, string enforceQuery)
    {
        LogController.CheckUser();

        // POST api/log/post_data?machine_name=&category_name=&counter_name=&instance_name=&log_name=&seconds=
        if (machine_name != null && category_name != null && counter_name != null && log_name != null && seconds.HasValue && enforceQuery == null)
        {
            List<LogInfo> dataVal = logDB.LogTimedPerfData(machine_name, category_name, counter_name, instance_name,
                                   log_name, live, seconds);
            logDB.SaveChanges();
            return dataVal;

        }

        return new List<LogInfo>();
    }
```

## **UPDATE:**

So, I updated the hub method so that it is now

```
public void SendToClient(List<DataValueInfo> json)
{
    Clients.showValue(json);
}
```

In my repository method, I updated it so that it has

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/PerfMon2");
hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
var perfMon = hubConnection.CreateProxy("LiveHub");                    //            
perfMon.On("showValue", json => Console.WriteLine(json));
hubConnection.Start().Wait();

List<DataValueInfo> lol = new List<DataValueInfo>();
for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
{
    data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
    dataValues.Add(data);
    lol.Add(new DataValueInfo
    {
        Value = perfCounter.NextValue().ToString()
    });
    perfMon.Invoke<List<DataValueInfo>>("SendToClient", lol);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Still no luck. Is it because I'm using Console.WriteLine, which doesn't work with browsers? If not that, what can I use? As already noted, Javascript is out of the question since I'm not working with a View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding some of the SignalR basics as I see no call to `Clients` in your hub, which means you're not broadcasting anything.

The public method on your hub (i.e. your Send() method) is pretty useless right now, as it just returns the data you pass into it. If you want to broadcast from the server to connected clients, you need to use the `Clients` dynamic property in the hub method and invoke a method on it.

Reading through these docs should give you a better picture of how this is supposed to work: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Comment: Thanks. So to clarify, would this involve using On method before starting the connection in order to subscribe to a method in the Hub that uses the Clients keyword? I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: A pointer in the right direction. If you see my update and reply, that would be great, because it simply isn't helping. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like SignalR only works with C# when in a desktop application, and only works with Javascript/jquery when used in a web app. It doesn't seem to work from a MVC model using C# code like what I need, or maybe it is just impossible to have a dynamic Web API call via URL?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Is this your scenario (correct me if I'm wrong): you are issuing an HTTP GET request to a WebAPI endpoint that does some lengthy processing and you want to return/stream JSON data to the *same* request as soon as it is ready? SignalR will not help in this case (it can't write to the output stream WebAPI is using), instead you should take a look at `PushStreamContent` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/23/using-cookies-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) which allows you to asynchronously write to the output stream.

Comment: You are correct, and after a fair amount of labor, I realized that SignalR was not helpful in this scenario.
As for the second part of your comment, you sir, are a hero. That looks like precisely what I needed!